# Can anyone shed some light on why this code from the alpaca-py documentation does not work?

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to stream bitcoin data using the alpaca-py trading documentation but I keey getting a invalid syntax error. This is taken exactly from the alpaca-py documentation. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
from typing import Any
from alpaca.data.live import CryptoDataStream

wss_client = CryptoDataStream(key-id, secret-key)

# async handler
async def quote_data_handler(data: Any):
    # quote data will arrive here
    print(data)

wss_client.subscribe_quotes(quote_data_handler, "BTC")

wss_client.run()
```

Comment: At what line do you receive your syntax error?
I'd suppose it is on line 8 because of the comment directly after the function definition but I can't tell for sure.

Comment: It doesn't even give me a line that the error is happening on which is strange. It literally only says ```error: invalid syntax (400)```. Also, tried deleting that comment and it did not work unfortunately

Comment: What's the return code of your script, does it execute?
If it's not an error from python I'd guess it is a error from your Request your doing.
The return code 400 is a code for 'Invalid Request'.
If that's the case, the error is not from python, the language, but rather from the library making an invalid web request.

Comment: ahhh figured it out. They had changed the Ticker symbol in the last update. should be BTCUSD not BTC

Comment: I am also having the same issue, and the change from the "BTC" ticker to "BTCUSD" does not fix the problem for me :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a look at the dashes in your parameters. Usually a no-no in most languages since the "-" or dash usually refers to a minus which is a binary operator or an operator that operates on two operands to produce a new value or result."
2. Make sure parameters are set before passing them.
3. Try the underscore instead as in: key_id = "".
4. Also useful is the following link to a comprehensive list of crypto pairs supported by Alpaca: [https://alpaca.markets/support/alpaca-crypto-coin-pair-faq/#:~:text=For%20the%20initial%20launch%20of,%2C%20SOL%2C%20TRX%2C%20UNI](https://alpaca.markets/support/alpaca-crypto-coin-pair-faq/#:%7E:text=For%20the%20initial%20launch%20of,%2C%20SOL%2C%20TRX%2C%20UNI))
5. Stay up to date on the above list as it's membership may be a bit volatile at the moment.